# Android encryption/Decryption issue

Tags: android, encryption

I am doing an encryption decryption of file in android, for this purpose I am using following code

```
private void encryptFile()
{
    try
    {
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images.jpg");
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        int num = in.read(buffer, 0, 100);
        Encryption mEncryption = new Encryption("test");
        File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/temp.jpg");
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        os.write(mEncryption.encrypt(buffer), 0, 100);
        while(in.read(buffer) != -1)
        {
            os.write(buffer);
        }
        in.close();
        os.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void decryptFile()
{
    try
    {
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/temp.jpg");
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        in.read(buffer, 0, 100);
        Encryption mEncryption = new Encryption("test");
        File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images.jpg");
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        os.write(mEncryption.decrypt(buffer), 0, 100);
        while(in.read(buffer) != -1)
        {
            os.write(buffer);
        }
        in.close();
        os.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but when I decrypt file its giving me `IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption` any Idea why its happening?

**Edit:** I am using this [**Encryption class**](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2010/09/story-of-android-cryptography-and.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many potential problems with this code. What is the `Encryption` class? It is not part of standard Android SDK. Are you not intending to encrypt the whole file? This code is only encrypting the first 100 bytes. And this is where the major fault is. The code then assumes that the first 100 bytes of input file will contain encrypted data, this is an invalid assumption. The encrypted data will for a start be normalised to the length of the block size of the encryption algorithm.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I am trying to encode/decode only first 100 bytes of data as encrypting the whole file will take to much time I have posted link to my encryption class above

Comment: Ok, then look at the resulting buffer from the mEncryption.encrypt(buffer) in the encryptFile method. Your decryptFile code is assuming this is 100 bytes, it won't be. You will need to store this somewhere and read back the correct amount of encrpted data that is then passed to decrypt.

Comment: yeah its greater than 100 bytes and I thinks thats the problem, but now when I decrypt the file how come I know how much bytes are really encrypted to be read and decrypt them any idea on this I mean how can I only encrypt first 100 bytes of file and then decrypt them at later time

Comment: You will need to store the length of the encrypted data in the file.

Answer (score 2):

the Encryption class you are using was posted on my blog like you said ( http://blog.kotowicz.net/2010/09/story-of-android-cryptography-and.html ) but as an example of how you SHOULDN'T implement the encryption! It has some certain padding and key expansion problems, all mentioned in the blog post.

The class comes from the source of this class comes from Android Remote Notifier project. If you really need it, at least use the corrected version http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/source/browse/trunk/AndroidNotifier/src/org/damazio/notifier/util/Encryption.java - the version in my blog post has some serious issues.

As Nic Strong mentioned, you are encountering padding - block ciphers align to block size and you should account for that.

Comment: thanks for enlightening me, now I have created my own helper class and working on that